# Log specific database queries in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, grep

Is it possible to log queries executed only on a particular database in postgresql?

One possible solution is to log the database name, and finally grep them. Would be helpful if there is a better approach, as the log generated is humongous that grep is not very convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contrib module pg_stat_statements would be able to do that:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html

Because it only tracks statements for the database where the module was installed.

Comment: any insight on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786949/duration-logged-but-not-the-statement-postgresql-are-there-any-specific-quer